# How to include values in crosstab even if the count is zero

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I am counting 'visits' by hour of day and date but want the output to include all 24 hours regardless of whether there were visits or not.

This is my query:

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Count([ServiceEncounterID]),0) AS CountOfServiceEncounterID
SELECT DateValue([EDRegistrationDtm]) AS DOY, HisDataModel_1.HourOD
FROM HisDataModel AS HisDataModel_1
GROUP BY DateValue([EDRegistrationDtm]), HisDataModel_1.HourOD
ORDER BY DateValue([EDRegistrationDtm])
PIVOT HisDataModel_1.Stream;
```

This give me the following output:
[Results-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzvHf.png)

As you can see I am missing lines where there are no visits (Hour 1 and 2) - I want to include lines for hour 1 and 2 with zero counts. Is this possible?

Comment: JOIN or UNION the CROSSTAB to a dataset of all possible date/hour pairs or create 'dummy' records in data.

Comment: This is a common topic so Google it "crosstab query show row even if no data". One result https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/columns-or-rows-missing-crosstab-if-they-contain-no-data#:~:text=If%20a%20crosstab%20row%20or%20column%20contains%20no,determined%20by%20the%20result%20set%20of%20the%20query.